# If PF is withdrawn by an NRI staying in USA does it become taxable as per US laws?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, india, provident-fund

I have been service in an Indian company for 10 years and now getting transferred to US. I want to keep the PF and not withdraw as I don't need money and it will earn good 8.5% interest for next 3 years. I heard that if I withdraw this money later when I start filling taxes in US all the interest earned on PF (even the interest in previous years and not just these 3 years) will need to be declared as income and would come under tax. Is this true?
My assumption was that only interest earned after I convert to NRI status is the one which becomes taxable. Please clarify.

Comment: I guess you'd be better off talking to a professional, but in general, it is best to explain the terms you're asking about or at least refer to the legal system you're asking about. I added the tags for you, since it is clear that you're asking about some Indian retirement system.

Answer (score 2):

According to indian laws :

> Any interest income accrued on EPF post retirement/resignation is
>   taxable in your hands

So if India is taxing it, there should be a dtaa with US, which can help you out.

[Reference:](https://www.relakhs.com/epf-interest-income-withdrawals-taxation/)